# Throbbing dup-hammer tooltip

Tags: discussion, bug

When viewing, *in Firefox 51*, a question that has been dup-hammer closed there is a banner showing the tag under which it was dup-hammered.  When you mouse over the dup-hammer tag, a tooltip comes up explaining why a single user was allowed to close the question.  This tooltip is z-order positioned in front of the tag icon which, if the mouse cursor is positioned just right, causes it to throb.

Probably not intended, but maybe cool, I'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a link to the question?  Also, what browser/OS are you on?

Comment: Happens on any question that is dup-hammer closed, when mousing over the gold-badge tag that resulted in the dup-hammer.

Comment: Reason I'm asking for more specifics:  I see the tooltip on the *outside* of the badge, which means that your specific z-fighting issue isn't one I could reproduce on Chrome.

Comment: @Makoto good question, I've updated my question to be more specific.